# Auto filter refuses to work in locked sheet in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is used for configuring IP phone system configurations. Bascially I have a table that has the following info in it;

```
Part No.        Description        Qty       Price
```

I have the filter set on the `qty` column to only show Qty amounts greater than `0`.
I have some VBA script that auto updates the filter as soon as input values change

As sourced from [How to I auto-refresh an Excel auto-filter when data is changed?](https://superuser.com/questions/249758/how-to-i-auto-refresh-an-excel-auto-filter-when-data-is-changed), this works great, and the whole sheet works better than I could have hoped.

BUT, I want to lock the sheet so I can restrict entry to just the few cells needed, as this needs to be sent out to the end users, as well as hiding my cost prices etc etc.

If I lock the sheet then the filter gets completely removed (as in not even in place anymore) and shows every part in the table.

Can anyone suggest how I can get around this?

Comment: I was able to duplicate this problem on Excel 2007. The filter gets removed after I change a value in one of the unlocked filtered cells. Happens only when the sheet is protected, even when I have "Sort" and "Use Autofilter" checked off.

Comment: Thanks for confirming Kaze.... now who can tell me how to fix it ??  :)