# How do I auto-refresh an Excel auto-filter by colour when the colour of cells is changed?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do i auto-update an Excel auto-filter (filter by colour) when the colour of cells is changed?

Use case: I change the colour of one cell to the colour that was filtered. I want to see the current row disappearing without having to do anything else.

i was able to use VB given for the value-change-row-disappearing case from: [How to I auto-refresh an Excel auto-filter when data is changed?](https://superuser.com/questions/249758/how-to-i-auto-refresh-an-excel-auto-filter-when-data-is-changed)

but don't know how to make it work for colour case.
tnx.

Answer (score 1):

You would need an event to track the color changing of a cell.
Yet, there is **no such event in Excel VBA.**

The only way to use an event would be to use: `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

So the code would be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'code described in the other question
```

But this is probably overkill as it will refresh your filter every time you select a new cell.

Comment: Could we track `.colorindex` changing?

Comment: No you can't *track* it. You can track when the `Value` is changing only

Comment: Don't take me as challenging you, just trying to learn. What if we set a var for the colorindex number and tracked that value of it changing? Or are you saying the only thing to track changing is cell.value?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my answer. You can find [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) some information about which events you can track. This will explain how you can use `Worksheet_Change` to track when the *value* of the cell is changing whereas `Worksheet_SelectionChange` will track the *Selection change*. You cannot store the value of the color index of **every cell** of the worskheet so I don't think that would work. I hope this is clearer :)

Comment: Pulling out the soapbox for a second, color is NOT data.  In every instance where I've helped users with their spreadsheets using conditional formatting with an in-cell drop down solved their problems and gave proper data to sort without relying on color as data.