# how come excel refreshes only when I save?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

A certain xlsx file I work on refreshes (recalcc to cells) only when I save in Office 2010.
How come? How can I change it?

Comment: go to formulas and on the right there are calculation options, make sure it's automatic.

Comment: @Raystafarian: prefer your solution over the accepted answer. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Excel will refresh when you press F9

Alternatively you could have a macro running that refreshed on a given time.

e.g.

```
Sub turnoff()
'Turn Off calculation and start call ontime routine
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Call DoTimer
End Sub

Sub DoTimer()
'Call the sheet calculation macro every one second
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Rep"

End Sub
```

> Sub Rep() ' calculate the sheet and repeat the ontime process
>   Sheet1.Calculate
>   Call DoTimer
>   End Sub

Source: [Here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=531807)

**EDIT:**

You can also check in Options - Formulas - Calculation Options to ensure that automatic calculations is turned on.
[image]

Comment: F9 indeed works, however in all other workbooks each time I change a cell all the dependent cells update automatically, that is the default behavior of Excel. Only this file acts weird. Do you know how I can reactivate the auto-refresh?

Comment: Does this question help: http://superuser.com/questions/249758/how-to-i-auto-refresh-an-excel-auto-filter-when-data-is-changed

Comment: Go into Options - Formulas - Calculation Options. (Top left) That's where it is set.