# Copy column to automatically update in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I currently have a column of numbers in, say, sheet A. I'd like to copy this column to sheet B which is easy enough.
However, if i make a change to a value in the column in sheet A is there a way to make the value automatically alter in sheet B? 
(I am working on a Mac but answers in either Windows or Mac would be helpful).

Currently, sheet A is a long list of numbers and sheet B is identical with the duplicates removed. If I add a new value into A I would like this to automatically appear in B.

Comment: The change is only new value or modification of value also?

Comment: Yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

You will need a macro to accomplish this. You can create this macro and then assign it to a button or keyboard shortcut.

Sub RemoveDups()

'Clear the destination column 
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).ClearContents

'Copy/paste values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 
Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)

'Remove duplicates from Sheet2 
Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo

End Sub

Comment: Hi Thank you for this! I'm not very good with macros - where do I type this?

Comment: There are a lot of videos that can walk you through creating a module. Here is one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T--ZZSQhGqU

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Macro for this and you can live with the need to refresh a filter manually when you update the data, then I can give you an idea:

In Sheet2 simply use a formula replicate the Sheet1 column by copying the corresponding cells from sheet1 (you said this is easy so I won't explain more).

Then, in an adjacent column in Sheet2 put a formula to count the occurrences of the value in the row from the first row to the one you are

Example:

Column A contains same Sheet1 values (something like `=Sheet1!A1` on A1 and so on)

Column B contains `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)` on B1 (notice first part of the cells range is blocked using $ so first row will remain fixed as you...) then copy the formula down.
What you will get will be the number of occurrences of what is on column A increasing from top to bottom.

Last thing you'll need to do is simply put a filter on column B to hide all rows which have on column B a value > 1.

(Remember you'll also need to copy formulas in column A and B down if you insert new data on column A on Sheet1 if you don't do it in advance)

P.S.
There would be a very simple way to [make the filter refresh automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/249758/how-to-auto-refresh-an-excel-auto-filter-when-data-is-changed/1217917#1217917)... but then you need a macro (a simple one thus)